# Using AWS DataStore.query returns an object whose properties are parsed objects, but linter expects a string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-datastore

When I use `DataStore.query` to retrieve data, I am getting conflicting data types from my linter. Contrived example:

**schema.graphql**

```
type Card @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }]) {
  id: ID!
  input: AWSJSON  
}
```

**react component javascript:**

```js
 const originalCard = await DataStore.query(Card, cardid);
 // originalCard.input is of type string | undefined | null according to my linter
 if(!originalCard.input) return; // Ignore non-string cases
 await DataStore.save(
   Card.copyOf(originalCard, (updated) => {
     updated.input = JSON.stringify(originalCard.input);
   })
 );
```

The above should simply save the same input as it has already received. And this is accepted by my linter. The problem is that when I run the code, I get an error, which advises that the `originalCard.input` value is actually an object. So it seems that `DataStore.query` is parsing the `input` value for me, which is great, except that the linter is being given the wrong information.

The cheap and dirty fix is just to tell typescript that the `input` value is in fact an object: `...as unknown as Record<string,any>`, but I suspect there's a better way and/or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding a type narrowing check, so that TypeScript can statically analyse the logic path:

```js
const originalCard = await DataStore.query(Card, cardid);
if(typeof originalCard.input === 'object') {
  await DataStore.save(
   Card.copyOf(originalCard, (updated) => {
     updated.input = JSON.stringify(originalCard.input);
   })
 );
}
```

So this would replace `if(!originalCard.input) return;`

Comment: The  `if(!originalCard.input) return;` line returns out if the `input` value is `undefined` or `null`. If I use your method then I'll not return out when `input` is `null`, which isn't what I want.